# Injecting property files overriding the one defined in the application

Tags: java, spring

I need some help on injecting property value to a bean which is defined outside the web application.

The web application has a property file under src/main/resource.The spring application context xml has the property place holder defined as

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:test.properties,file:/etc/test1.properties"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true"
    />
```

where test1.properties is another file which resides outside the application.The bean is injected with the property which is defined in the application (test.properties) ,but I want to inject the property that is defined in test1.properties (ideally the idea is to override the property values from application and read the one defined outside the application).

Thanks.

Comment: Which is how it should work, if it isn't I suspect your file isn't being read.

Comment: The bean is annotated with Component and the package is part of the component scan.So the spring container loads the bean and injects the dependency but does not read the property file values outside the application.Any pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: Then it doesn't find the file. I'm pretty sure that when you set `ignore-resource-not-found` to `false` your application breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:c:/kp/sec.properties" order="1" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:kp-props.properties" order="2" />
```

If the file sec.properties exists take the value from sec.properties, if file or properties does not exist take the property from kp-props.properties file from resources directory(if the property is not found in either of place application will fail)

And say you have property `my.prop` and you can inject the property as follows.

```
@Component
public class KPProps {

    @Value("${my.prop}")
    private int props;

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(props);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi use like below in applicationContext.xml

```
<util:properties id="property" location="classpath:test.properties"/>
```

In Java,

```
@Autowired
    protected Properties property;
```